# How to fix the error "Registration on php site"

Tags: php

I can't do authorization on the site! I register everything is fine! But he does not want to enter the site! I do not know what to do ! + I use the md5 () function, and my database encrypts everything perfectly, but how to make it enter through this function too? Also not included without this feature, please help !!!

Here is the authorization code:

```
require("include/connect.php");
if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    // вывод "Session is set"; // в целях проверки
    header("Location: main.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['button-login'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password_1'])) {
        $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_1']);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='" . $login . "' AND password='" . $password . "'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows != 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $dbusername = $row['login'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password_1'];
            }
            if ($login == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
                // старое место расположения
                //  session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                header("Location: main.php");
            }
        } else {
            //  $message = "Invalid username or password!";

            echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "All fields are required!";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your `users` table structure?

Comment: Just want to mention that MD5 is not secure and is not *encryption*.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `firsname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: This code is really flawed and vulnerable. I would strongly encourage you abandon what you have and read some newer tutorials on **authentication** best practices for PHP. As for fixing this code. Have you debugged at all? How far through do you get and still have the expected results/values?

Comment: Well, ate to refuse this, then how can I make a normal authorization on the site, can you help me, is it possible to give a ready part of the authorization code?

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert the `$password` variable into `md5()`

```
$password = md5($password);
```

after `md5()` encryption check your username & password condition

```
if($login == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: I did but no reaction anyway